# Unit testing and factories for mocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

Suppose I have a class C that I need to test. Part of it's job is to create a number of other non-trivial class objects (each of which have their own business logic) and call various methods on these new objects. I want to be able to test class C without testing the implementation of those other objects that C creates. Is the only real solution to create a factory which creates those non-trivial objects, and then pass in a mocked factory instance into the test? I don't want to have a single factory to create those other non-trivial objects, but on the other hand I don't want to have a factory per non-trivial class.

Any other suggestions?

Edit: added some pseudo code as requested

```
public B doIt()
{
  List<A> as = getListOfAsFromDatabase();
  AParser AParser = new AParser();
  boolean foo = aParser.parse(as); // may modify the list of A's
  B b = new B();
  return b.add(foo, as);
}
```

Comment: Are you creating those non-trivial objects in one method? Can you parameterise them?

Comment: If you don't want a single factoy, and you also don't want one factory per class, then the only remaining choice is to pass a number of factories, each of them being responsible for the creation of 1 or several objects. Or maybe some of those objects should be grouped together as fields of another parent object, created by a parent object factory.

Comment: @Anatolii yes, creating in one method. What do you mean by parameterise them?

Comment: @JBNizet the case today is that I only need to create one non-trivial type of object. I'm OK with creating a factory for this one. My concern is if tomorrow I need to create 5 more non-trivial types of objects. Correct, I dont want to create 5 more factories. The parent factory/refactoring makes sense potentially in the future, but the object's can't be related/refactored in that way today.

Comment: @jordan can you please add some code explaining which method you want to test and which one you need to skip?

Comment: `What do you mean by parameterise them?` - create them in a different injector class and pass them as parameters to your method/constructor.

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam I added some made up pseudocode to illustrate the point. This "doIt" method is in the "C" class. I want to test that C correctly calls it's collaborators, but I don't want to test the logic of the A, AParser, B classes. Those classes will be unit tested in isolation.

Comment: You don't need `aParser.parse(as);`  to be executed when you run unit test?

Answer (score 0):

If the dependency object creation is at member level, we could possibly use Mockito and PowerMock to create mock and update member to mock dependency. I'm using static inner class to make this simple, this solution will work for regular class as well.

```
public class Test1 {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        B mockedb = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(B.class);
        A a = new A();
        org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.setInternalState(a, "b", mockedb);
        a.exe();
    }

    public static class A {
        private B b = new B();

        public void exe() {
            List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add("a");
            b.exeB(l);
            System.out.println(l);
        }

        public static class B {
            public void exeB(List<String> s) {
                s.add("b");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm aware of those reflection methods but they seem a hack to me.

Comment: It is just test code, it will not be included in your production code. But its up to you to make the call.